# RewriteRule to match string NOT containing dot (.) only if it also does not contain another specific word

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So, I'm trying to have a RegEx at my .htaccess that uses RewriteRule to redirect website.

My idea is to redirect all URLs that are not files, and I used to do it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Problem with this `^([^\.]+)/?$` **RegEx** is that URLs like following are not being rewrited when I want:

1. /username/my.username
2. /profile/another.username
3. /picture/some.user/latest

It worked really nice, but as soon as users started using dots (.) in their username, it obviously stopped working. I was assuming all URLs that have a dot (.) would be files, like these:

1. /assets/image.png
2. /index.html

The solution I'm thinking about would be to add a set of words that I know that are URLs that must be rewritten, like if the contain words like as **/username**, **/profile**, **/picture**

So... how can I build a **RegEx** expression in a way that:

1. It matches whenever a dot (.) is not present
2. OR if the dot (.) is present it should check if words like **/username**, **/profile**, **/picture** are present in the string.

I was trying something like this:

```
[^\.]|([\S]+(\b\/(profile|username)\/)+[\S])?
```

But obviously does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier would be to use `RewriteCond` like this to avoid rewriting any files and directories but let pattern match anything:

```bash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Great! Exactly what I would have answered also :-)

Comment: Oh, it works! I'm glad I mentioned that it was for .htaccess rewriting :-)